# Fstream searching a textfile for a word

Tags: c++

So I have to let the user input a text file and my program is supposed to search for this text file and once its found, it'll search for a word in that text file, and count how many times a number appeared in this file.I'm having trouble writting the code for simply searching for the word in the text file. Please help. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string dog;
    int word; 
    int TheFile; 



    cout << "enter the name of file and I'll search for it: " << endl;
    cin >> name;

    //opening the file
    TheFile.open(name, ios::out);

    if (file)
    {
        cout << "enter the word you want to search for: " << endl;
        cin >> word;
        getline(file, word);

//stuck here

        for (unsigned int Numline = 0; getline(TheFile, SearchWord);NumLine++)
            if (SearchWord.find)
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "the file " << NameofFile << " does not exist!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you're read the search word, you want to leave it alone.

After that, you want to read lines from the file into some other (string) variable. Then you want to search for the search word in that string (e.g., using `input_line.find(search_word)`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Use while(getline(TheFile, Line)) for looping and then use string::find to search for the SearchWord in the Line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name; 
    cout << "enter the name of file : " << endl;
    cin >> name;

    // opening the file
    fstream TheFile; 
    TheFile.open(name, ios::in);

    if (TheFile.is_open())
    {
        string word; // hold the word user inputs to be searched for
        cout << "enter the word: " << endl;

        string Line;
        unsigned int found = 0;
        while (getline(TheFile, Line)) {
            if (Line.find(word) != string::npos)
                ++found;
        }

        cout << "the word " << word << " was found " << found << " times" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "the file " << name << " does not exist!" << endl;
    }

    cout << "press enter to exit " << endl;
    int c = getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is clearly homework and you've done the work for the op - in the future, provide *guidance* (see Jerry's answer) rather than actual code...